# onClick Function for Link Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery & JavaScript and have been hacking away to try and get a function working on my website.

The page loads with sections hidden via CSS and revealed when the user clicks a link. I have it working but in trying to make it more usable later for other buttons I am trying to turn it into a function which cause it to break.

```
$(".bed-breakfast-explore").hide();
$("#bed-breakfast-menu").hide();       

function discoverBedBreakfast() {    

    $(".bed-breakfast-explore").slideToggle("slow");

    $(".hotel").css("display", "none");
    $(".resort").css("display", "none");
    $(".guest-house").css("display", "none");

    $("#bed-breakfast-menu").show();        

    $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $('#bed-breakfast-menu').offset().top - 86}, 1300);

}
```

The HTML for the link is:

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="discoverBedBreakfast()">Explore</a>
```

Comment: May be you should explain little more about your problem, because your code works fine here. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f63zny67/)

Comment: The javascript function is probably declared _after_ the HTML. When using inline `onclick`, the referred function must be present at load time.

Comment: @davidkonrad Maybe that is the issue. Because he code sits at bottom of the HTML body. if I avoid using onclick and use JQuery to detect the click instead it works fine.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla Yes I see it working, interesting. As I just mentioned below it is probably because of the code residing at the base of the HTML.

Comment: Place the javascript inside `<head></head>`

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla Interesting placing inside `<head>` does not seem to work.

Comment: According to the comments above, seems like the problem lies elsewhere. Can you please set up a JSFiddle so people can have a look and track mistakes.

Comment: @davidkonrad: That's not true at all.

Comment: @rainwilds: Putting it in the `<head>` isn't going to help. Is the function inside another function? This is often the issue. Do you show errors in your developer console? This is the first place you should be looking.

Comment: ...and we do not need a jsFiddle. We do need a complete yet minimal example of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

place it like

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script >
    $(document).ready(function(){


    $(".bed-breakfast-explore").hide();
    $("#bed-breakfast-menu").hide();

    })


    function discoverBedBreakfast() {    

        $(".bed-breakfast-explore").slideToggle("slow");

        $(".hotel").css("display", "none");
        $(".resort").css("display", "none");
        $(".guest-house").css("display", "none");

        $("#bed-breakfast-menu").show();        

        $('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $('#bed-breakfast-menu').offset().top - 86}, 1300);

    }
    </script>
</head>
```